# React context updates in same function body are aggregated as a single transaction with data store, is this expected behavior?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-redux, react-context

While using a `React Context` pattern I've had success with as of late, I ran into an issue of which I'd like to have better understanding.

The pattern is described by the code at the link below. Essentially, I am using the context API to create a singleton class. I've enjoyed this pattern because it maintains immutability, but provides some nice OO functionality.

The issue I am running into is that context `dispatch` updates are not being propagated individually if they are called within the same ~member function. It seems like they are being aggregated into one transaction. This is great for performance in some scenarios. But, not so much here.

**Sample member function:**

```
export const makeRunCapiProcess = (state : CapiContextI)=>(process : ()=>void)=>{ 
    

   
       const capiProcessName = Shortid.generate();

       state.dispatch({
        type: "def",
        payload: {
            ...state,
            core : {
                ...state.core,
                [capiProcessName] : process
            }
        }
    })

    process()

    // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    // THIS IS THE PROBLEM AREA
    // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

    // Updates to context state are only propagated after this call.
    // Can circumvent this by wrapping in async or using setTimeout,
    // but that has resulted in a failure to set some proccesses to false.
    // I have also tried using a state.forceUpdate() here, but to no avail.
    state.dispatch({
        type: "def",
        payload: {
            ...state,
            core : {
                ...state.core,
                [capiProcessName] : false
            }
        }
    })

    return capiProcessName;


}
```

**Minimum reproducible example:** [Check it out on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-butterfly-8nlns?file=/src/Example.tsx)

As noted in the comments, I can kind of get around this issue with a `setTimeout` or an `async` IIE, but this results in other issues.

I will note that I'm using CRA [default](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js); I've wondered if this might be some clever-not-so-clever compiler trick.

**Edit 1:** As now noted in the comments, I have also tried to add a forceUpdate member to the singleton. But, this seems to be invoked after both calls are made, thus not solving my problem.

**Edit 2:** I'm still curious about just what's happening behind the scenes here. But, I think that this is too imperative of a pattern. If you find this post and you're looking to do something similar, I think it's generally going to be better to implement this by providing some kind of state change that then triggers a clean-up in the provider's useEffect.

Comment: Should not you dispatch actions from the `useEffect`?

Comment: @Shota Honestly, I'm not sure. I've seen other people pass state setters around like this. But, I don't know enough about the deep inner workings of react to know if this is hacky. FYI, I have also tried this with a forceUpdate in between the two calls and that has not worked either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Partially answering my own question:**

Don't try to run multiple context updates in a single function. They are batched. See this thread on the React GitHub for more: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/21899